# How to layout complicated view with lots of tableview cells and autolayout constrainsts where storyboard is failing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a view like this
[image]

[image]

Basically it is lots of static tableview cells , where each cell has horizontal scroll views and stack views. Now trying this in storyboard has slowed down it completely, where adding or deleting a constraint or just changing label text in Xcode 9 takes more than 30 seconds and there is always a spinning beachball. 
What are the ways I can reduce system overload or make storyboard a bit faster.
Or is it better to move to laying out views in code. In that case any help / advice in this regard will be highly welcome.
Thanks in advance for your efforts.

[Here is the link to GitHub repo for the same](https://github.com/nikhilpandey4/Stackoverflow_Storyboard_19Oct2017)

Comment: I know this is frustrating. But I think there is hardly anything you can do about it. The more view hierarchy and layouting you have the more slower it becomes. And be assured that `UIStackView` inside `UITablewView` is surely gonna be such a pain in the ass.

Comment: Separate it into multiple xibs, then combine in code, it would be better than putting everything in single storyboard

Comment: I have to get lots of inputs from users and if I separate it into multiple xibs, I have to use lots and lots of custom delegates for passing data into view controller and subsequent computations, as well as passing data around. In this case for each cell a part of the cell is used for input and a part is being used for the output.

Comment: I think @Tj3n's solution is the best you can do. of course you have to write some delegates to pass data through your cells, tableview, controller, etc. But if you put everything in a single storyboard, for accessing different parts of each cell, you may want to use their tags.

Although I recommend using different xib files, you can also use some libraries like SnapKit, PureLayout, ... to layout your views in cells programaticaly.

Comment: IBDesignables. Extract the common components into views with xibs. Frankly, if you dont start separating things into components, your controller will have thousands of lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a few prototype cells, instead of repeating static cells that are virtually identical. You have at most 6 unique types of cells here. For example, Inputs A, D, E are the same. Inputs B, C, F are the same.

It's beyond the scope of the question to explain how to do this in detail,  but the basic procedure is as follows.

Let's say you want to add a prototype cell that you can use for Inputs B, C and F. This is your most basic input cell that will have one text field.

1. Add to your project a new class that inherits from UITableViewCell.
   Name it something like `BasicInputCell`.
2. Open your storyboard, select your table view and open the Attributes inspector. Increment the Prototype Cells setting by 1. Xcode will add a prototype cell to your table view in the storyboard
3. Select the prototype cell and open the Identity inspector. Set the Class name to the name of your cell, `BasicInputCell`.
4. Open the Attributes inspector and set the Identifier to the same value so that you can dequeue it by this name.
5. Add a text field to the cell in the storyboard. Open the Assistant Editor and Control drag from the text field to your class to create an IBOutlet.
6. Repeat for as many unique cell types as you need. Customize each cell type with different controls on it, such as date picker, as needed.

In your table view controller, dequeue the cells of the type you need based on the index path.

Comment: Yeah , I agree. How to do it . Should I use storyboard or layout it in code. I am now inclined towards using code but as per Apple auto layout guide one should use coding only if one is fully convinced that the views can not be laid out properly via storyboard. I want some advice on how to do that.

Comment: I would recommend a storyboard. See my updated answer. Good luck!